# How to create fields from raw text field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with a raw text data field separated by pipes
e.g. |Field1|Field2|Field3, etc

I need to extract these fields so that documents can be queried / filtered on them.
I'm confused between mappings, scripts and analysers....
Can somebody please point me at the right direction?

Comment: use a python script to extract the data out of the document and then use the extracted data {field1} to index in ES

Comment: thanks Nishant, can you please point me at an example of field extraction? I already added python to the ES plugins and scripting works i my server

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you mean you have a document in ElasticSearch already (document is a term used to represent a record in ElasticSearch) or you mean document like a CSV or text file and are asking how to parse it. Please provide more details and some examples.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. Yes, I already have a document indexed in ES. I now need to query filtering by these pipe separated fields. 
My example:

`POST /log_entry/logentry
    {
  "message": "{\"message\": \"2016-02-04 16:39:00.3597|TRACE|TrafficLogger|HTTP Response: POST http://myapi.cloudapp.net/v1/event/ -Headers: {Connection : \"Close\"; Authorization : \"f145cdf5-65fb-4ac0-8bbf-6aa70918df93\"; Expect : \"100-continue\"; Host : \"myapi.cloudapp.net\"} \r\nBad Request\" }"
    }`
now I want entries where Host =="myapi.cloudapp.net", and the date is in a date range (e.g. last week)